# Puppet agent freeze on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I have 40 Ubuntu 12.04 servers. These servers are managed with puppet.
Sometimes I have problem with puppet agent.
puppet agent spawn child process (sh) and this process fails. Sh is zombie process. Puppet doesn't work, I must restart puppet agent to make it works.

I use puppet to manage files, packages and services. Problematic agent didn't make any change before fails, server is up to date.

Comment: Are you running puppet as a daemon or as a cron job?  What's the full command of the `sh` process?  (You can use `ps aux | grep sh` for this.)

Comment: sh, it's only sh, this is weird.

Comment: root@XXX:~# ps aux | grep 13281
root     13281  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    15:43   0:00 [sh] <defunct>

Comment: Maybe you have a bad `Exec` declaration in your puppet manifests, like with mismatched quotes, empty command, or something?

Comment: On other nodes with same configuration is ok.

Comment: IMO, you should skip daemonized agent and just run puppet from cron. It is more reliable in my experience.  `9 * * * * root /usr/bin/puppet agent --no-daemonize --onetime`

Comment: can you run the agent with a --trace and see where it stops? 

Do you use any recursive file resources? They can case a hang on the master when doing diffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution:

I use puppet to manage cron script to restart puppet if agent freeze. :)